# MongoDB - Updating all matching Nested Documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have this MongoDB Document Collection. I would like to update a PropertyContractors Phone number for all documents where "ContractorTelephone": "0865215486".

```
{
"_id": "4",
"PropertyType": "House",
"PropertyNameNumber": "49",
"PropertyStreet": "Paul Street",
"PropertyTown": "Farmleigh",
"PropertyCity": "Waterford City",
"PropertyCounty": "Co Waterford",
"PropertyBedrooms": "3",
"PropertyDescription": "Central, Cheap",
"PropertyFacilities": [
    {
        "FacilitiesSmoking": "Yes",
        "FacilitiesPets": "Yes",
        "FacilitiesBroadBand": "Yes",
        "FacilitiesTV": "Yes"
    }
],
"PropertyAvailable": "1",
"PropertyContractor": [
    {
        "ContractorName": "John Murphy",
        "ContractorTelephone": "0865215486",
        "ContractorType": "Plumber"
    }
]
```

}

Ive Tried

```
db.Property.update(
{ PropertyContractor.ContractorTelephone: "0865215486" },
{
  $set: { PropertyContractor.ContractorTelephone: "0854854215" }
},
  { multi: true }
 )
```

But it just says that the . is wrong Syntax

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this could work?
  $set: { "PropertyContractor.ContractorTelephone": "0854854215" }

Comment: If you mena tjust literally copy in $set: { "PropertyContractor.ContractorTelephone": "0854854215" } it still throws a Syntax error with :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)**, it identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array:

```
db.Property.update(
    { 
       "PropertyContractor.ContractorTelephone": "0865215486" 
    },
    {
        "$set": {
           "PropertyContractor.$.ContractorTelephone": "0854854215" 
        }
    },
    { "multi": true }
 );
```

Comment: @ChrisMaher No worries :-)